# Trying to write code to go to the amazon app store

Tags: android

I am selling a puzzle up that always peaple to upgrade to a full version by bringing them to my app page on Google play. (using the following code)

```
   Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.fairhvaenapps.toddpuzzle");
   Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
   try {
       startActivity(goToMarket);
   } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
       Toast.makeText( cGlobals.MainHome, "Couldn't launch market", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

I would like to do this for the amazon app store to, but I could not find any documentation on how to do it.

Comment: https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
amzn://apps/android?p=com.something
```

https://developer.amazon.com/post/Tx3A1TVL67TB24B/Linking-To-the-Amazon-Appstore-for-Android.html